# Converting a list of tab- and newline-delimited character vectors into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, delimiter, csv

I have an object [res](/questions/tagged/res) which is a list of tab- and newline-delimited character vectors.

```
 >dput(res)
 list("# BLASTP 2.11.0+\n# Query: tr|A4I9M8|A4I9M8_LEIIN 
 Hypothetical_protein_-_conserved OS=Leishmania infantum OX=5671 
 GN=LINF_340011400 PE=4 SV=1\n# RID: HT7Z4V6H016\n# Database: nr\n# 
 Fields: subject id, evalue, % query coverage per subject, % identity\n# 
 35 hits found\nref|XP_001468447.1|\t8.15e- 
 82\t100\t100.000\nref|XP_001686149.1|\t1.33e- 
 73\t100\t90.984\ndbj|GET92147.1|\t4.31e- 
 67\t99\t82.645\ngb|KAG5468145.1|\t2.87e- 
 66\t100\t82.787\nref|XP_003878644.1|\t1.96e- 
 64\t100\t88.525\n# BLASTP 2.11.0+\n# Query: tr|A4HT95|A4HT95_LEIIN 
 Centrin_-_putative OS=Leishmania infantum OX=5671 GN=LINF_070012700 
 PE=3 SV=1\n# RID: HT7Z4V6H016\n# Database: nr\n# Fields: subject id, 
 evalue, % query coverage per subject, % identity\n# 512 hits 
 found\nref|XP_001463286.1|\t1.53e- 
 132\t100\t100.000\nref|XP_001680978.1|\t9.57e- 
 125\t100\t95.187\nref|XP_003872218.1|\t2.29e- 
 121\t100\t93.048\ndbj|GET86075.1|\t1.03e- 
 114\t97\t89.071\ngb|KAG5510937.1|\t1.50e- 
 103\t100\t80.214\ngb|KAG5486865.1|\t2.99e-103\t100\t84.492\n# BLAST 
 processed 2 queries\n", 
 "")
```

This is the structure of [res](/questions/tagged/res)

```
>str(res)
List of 2
$ : chr "# BLASTP 2.11.0+\n# Query: tr|A4I9M8|A4I9M8_LEIIN Hypothetical_protein_-_conserved 
OS=Leishmania infantum OX=56"| __truncated__
$ : chr ""
```

How do I convert [res](/questions/tagged/res) into a dataframe in R? The dataframe should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is horrible, but...

```
# remove the artificial newlines from sci notation
res_clean <- gsub("e- \n", "e-", res[[1]])

# split on newline -- each element is a row
res_split <- strsplit(res_clean[[1]], split = "\n")[[1]]

# get number of variables to add
num_vars <- max(sapply(strsplit(res_split, "\t"), length))

# create empty data frame with correct number of variables
dat <- read.csv(text = "", col.names = paste0("v", 1:num_vars))

# loop over rows to add
for (i in seq_along(res_split)) {
    # get row vector
    new_row <- strsplit(res_split[i], split = "\t")[[1]]
    # make sure row vector is correct length by appending with NAs
    new_row <- append(new_row, values = rep(NA, num_vars - length(new_row)), after = length(new_row))
    # add to data
    dat[i, ] <- new_row
}

> head(dat, 20)
                                                                      v1        v2   v3      v4
#1                                                       # BLASTP 2.11.0+      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#2                                       # Query: tr|A4I9M8|A4I9M8_LEIIN       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#3       Hypothetical_protein_-_conserved OS=Leishmania infantum OX=5671       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#4                                            GN=LINF_340011400 PE=4 SV=1      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#5                                                     # RID: HT7Z4V6H016      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#6                                                         # Database: nr      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#7                                                                     #       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#8   Fields: subject id, evalue, % query coverage per subject, % identity      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#9                                                                     #       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#10                                                         35 hits found      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#11                                                   ref|XP_001468447.1| 8.15e- 82  100 100.000
#12                                                   ref|XP_001686149.1| 1.33e- 73  100  90.984
#13                                                       dbj|GET92147.1| 4.31e- 67   99  82.645
#14                                                      gb|KAG5468145.1| 2.87e- 66  100  82.787
#15                                                   ref|XP_003878644.1| 1.96e- 64  100  88.525
#16                                                      # BLASTP 2.11.0+      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#17                                      # Query: tr|A4HT95|A4HT95_LEIIN       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#18  Centrin_-_putative OS=Leishmania infantum OX=5671 GN=LINF_070012700       <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#19                                                             PE=3 SV=1      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#20                                                    # RID: HT7Z4V6H016      <NA> <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but the dataframe looks distorted.

Comment: Ah yeah there were some artificial newlines in there. Check edit now, how does that look?

Comment: The rows with values in columns v2, v3, v4 are fixed. But the comment lines are split into multiple lines. Check the image attached with the question. That's how the dataframe should look like.

Comment: If you look at what's printed out from `res`, there are newlines everywhere (e.g., after the hashes which is why the comment lines are split into multiple lines). I'm not sure what you can do about that short of some selective `gsub` like I've shown an example of above.